# Función len, obtener items totales de las lista contenidas en diccionario

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

Estuve aplicando la función `len` en Python sobre un diccionario con listas. ¿En esta sentencia en Python porque al compilar devuelve "1"?

```
print len({0 :['a','bcd'],1 :['ef','ghi','k'],2 :['1'],}[1][1][1])
```

mi objetivo es obtener el total de elementos en conjunto de todas las listas del diccionario, 6 en este caso.

Comment: Hola Roberto, ¿Que esperas obtener exactamente? Con `{...}[1][1][1]` estas obteniendo una cadena de un solo carácter (`'h'`) y es sobre ella sobre la que aplicas `len`...

Comment: ¿Por casualidad esperas 6 como salida? El número total de items de todas las listas contenidas en el diccionario.

Comment: Si, para obtener 6 como debería hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El resultado es el esperado dado que haces `len({...}[1][1][1])`, un indizado encadenado. Si analizamos el código paso a paso se ve más claro:

- `{0: ['a', 'bcd'], 1: ['ef', 'ghi', 'k'], 2: ['1']}[1]`. Esto retorna el valor asociado a la clave `1` del diccionario, es decir `['ef', 'ghi', 'k']`.
- `['ef', 'ghi', 'k'][1]` esto obtiene el item en el indice 1 de la lista, la cadena `'ghi'`.
- `'ghi[1]'`: obtiene el carácter con el índice 1 de la cadena, con lo que obtenemos `"h"`
- `len("h")` nos retorna la longitud de la cadena, 1.

Para obtener el numero de elementos en conjunto de todas las listas del diccionario debes aplicar `len` a cada una de ellas iterando sobre el diccionario y luego sumar sus salidas:

```
>>> d = {0: ['a', 'bcd'], 1: ['ef', 'ghi', 'k'], 2: ['1']}
>>> print(sum(len(lista) for lista in d.values()))
6
```

o usando programación funcional:

```
>>> print(sum(map(len, d.values())))
6
```

Ten en cuenta que en ningún momento se comprueba que el valor sea una lista o que disponga siquiera del método `__len__` definido (como un entero). Si tu diccionario es heterogéneo debes tenerlo en cuanta y actuar en consecuencia.